# JavaFX, отслеживание действий пользователя

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из компонента `WebView` отследить куда на страничке нажал пользователь, и какие данные он ввел и в какой `<input>`?

Теперь конкретнее. Есть страничка, на которой несколько форм и сцылок. При вводе данных в `input` и нажатиях на `submit`, перед отправкой формы, надо запомнить `id` инпутов и значения которые были введены, для ссылок, просто отследить нажатие. Это для того, что бы робот обучался, и потом повторял действия пользователя.

Если-бы точно знать, какие `<input>` есть на страничке, можно было бы через `DOM` модель повешать обработчики `ChangeListener<String>`, но вот беда - каждый раз колличество `<input>` меняется, и с новыми `id` и именами. Так же и линки.

Вот и возникает вопрос: как отловить компоненты, на которые кликает пользователь, до отправки формы на сервер? И как отследить нажатие на ссылку, если не известен ее `id`?

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать положение мышки на сайте. `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().` 
А при каждом клике пользователя заносить параметры мыши в бд. А потом оттуда сделать симуляцию движения и кликов). А ID записать вы не можете, так как вам они не известны. Данные же форм, которые введены, можно отслеживать по нажатию клавиш.